# Drawing 2 lines between Dart Flutter listView items

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I have an application like this:

[image]

There is a line between each item. I want a line between every 2 item, not every item.

**Codes:**

```
body: Container(
  padding: EdgeInsets.all(7),
  child: Column(
    
    children: [
      
      Text(defaultFlag, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24),),
      SizedBox(height: 10,),


      Expanded(
        
        child: ListView.separated(
          itemCount: levels.length,
          separatorBuilder: (context, index) => Divider(
            thickness: 2,
            color: Colors.black,
          
          ),
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            return Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(2.0),
              child: Container(
                child: InkWell(
                  child: Container(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                      border: Border.all(color: Colors.black),
                    ),
                    child: ListTile(
                      leading: languageLevelIcon(levels[index].languageLevelName,),
                      title: Text(levels[index].languageLevelName, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25),),
                      trailing: Icon(Icons.arrow_forward_ios, color: Colors.black,),
                      
                      iconColor: Colors.black,
                    ),
                    
                    ),
                  onTap: () {
                    print("tıklandı " + levels[index].languageLevelName);
                  },
                ),
                
              ),
              
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
),
```

So there will be a line between A2 and B1, and between B2 and C1. I want a line between both items. How can I do it?

Comment: you want to line for first and last card same as other?

Comment: separatorBuilder: (context, index) => index%2 != 0 ? Divider(
            thickness: 2,
            color: Colors.black,
          
          ) : SizedBox(),

Comment: @Jim post it as an answer.

Comment: @Manohar I think someone has posted it for me already, it's ok~

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Jim has mentioned,

```
ListView.separated(
      itemCount: levels.length,
      separatorBuilder: (context, index) => index % 2 != 0 ? Divider(
        thickness: 2,
        color: Colors.black,
      ) : SizedBox(),
      itemBuilder: (context, i) {
        return <Your list tile>,
        );
      },
    ),
```